# RxSwift - PublishSubject - Ignore error and continue subscription (do not dispose)

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I could not find sufficient example on how to do this.

Essentially, we have a `PublishSubject` which is just a passthrough; and we do not have any operation on it. We believe we are dropping future events if there are any errors, since it is just a forward the value it receive as signal for subscribes, not sure why there would be an error.

[Assuming if it is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825795/rxswift-subscribe-block-not-called) (2nd comment to Q), how do we ignore any error on subject and keep the subscription alive?

If there is no option, is there a way to create a new subscription `onError` and keep listening to future `.next()`?

```
let pubSubj = PublishSubject<String>()
let obs = pubSubj
    .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .catchError { (err) -> Observable<String> in
        print("***** catchError \(err)\n")
        return .never() // expecting this not to terminate the subscription
    }

print("***** obs: \(obs)\n")


let dispose = obs.subscribe(onNext: { (str) in
    print("***** received onNext: \(str)\n")
}, onError: { (err) in
    print("***** received onErr: \(err)\n")
}, onCompleted: {
    print("***** completed\n")
}, onDisposed: {
    print("***** onDisposed\n")
})
                    
pubSubj.on(.next("2"))
pubSubj.onError(RxError.overflow) //emits error and terminates
            
pubSubj.on(.next("3")) //is not received, how can we keep from getting disposed
```

output:

```
***** obs: RxSwift.(unknown context at $1124f80f0).Catch<Swift.String>
***** received onNext: 2
***** catchError Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

Other Rx implementation seems to have [`onErrorResumeNext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059483/what-is-the-analog-of-rxjava-onerrorresumenext-operator-in-rxswift), which RxSwift doesn't support.

But there are answers points to .`catchError`, but from our example, it still disposes after the error and we do not receive "`3`"

Comment: Side note, where you wrote "emits error and terminates." That's not the case. Note that `onDisposed` was not called. By returning `never()` inside the catch, you ensure that the subscription doesn't terminate, but also that it never emits another value.

Comment: [system.reactive] is a .NET Tag

Comment: Thank you @DanielT I didn't notice the difference

Comment: @Enigmativity removed the tag, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to receive any event after receiving an error in a reactive stream because the stream will complete and this is always true for all the reactive libraries out there including RxSwift. `catch` will continue the stream using the `Observable` you return from the closure but there's no way for the outer stream to emit again:

```swift
  let pubSubj = PublishSubject<String>()
  let recover = PublishSubject<String>()
  let obs = pubSubj
    .catch { _ in
      recover
    }

  print("***** obs: \(obs)\n")


  let dispose = obs.subscribe(onNext: { (str) in
    print("***** received onNext: \(str)\n")
  }, onError: { err in
    print("***** received onErr: \(err)\n")
  }, onCompleted: {
    print("***** completed\n")
  }, onDisposed: {
    print("***** onDisposed\n")
  })
                      
  pubSubj.onNext("2")
  pubSubj.onError(RxError.overflow)
  pubSubj.onNext("3") // Will not be sent
  recover.onNext("3") // Will be sent
```

You have a couple of options to achieve what you need:

1. Do not feed errors in your `PublishSubject`. Essentially `pubSubj.onError(RxError.overflow)` should never happen.
2. If you need to feed errors in the `PublishSubject` then you can materialize it. In this way errors are sent as `next` events and stream will not complete eg:

```swift
  let pubSubj = PublishSubject<Event<String>>()
  let obs = pubSubj

  print("***** obs: \(obs)\n")


  let dispose = obs.subscribe(onNext: { (str) in
      print("***** received onNext: \(str)\n")
  }, onCompleted: {
      print("***** completed\n")
  }, onDisposed: {
      print("***** onDisposed\n")
  })
                      
  pubSubj.onNext(.next("2"))
  pubSubj.onNext(.error(RxError.overflow))
  pubSubj.onNext(.next("3"))
```